# Capture facebook comment after posting

Tags: comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a Facebook commenting section on my project. It works fine, I'm just wondering if I can capture the comments right after its posted so I can save the comment's content in my database?
Is there a way to capture 'post comment' event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Edge Events, specifically `comment.create`:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', comment_callback);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.6